# How to pass parameters to a Linux kernel with grub?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, battery, kubuntu

I have posted the question "Kubuntu 12.10 laptop battery dropping fast" and there i have received the answer as

accept
As advised on another Stack Exchange forum, the procedure to accomplish an answer to your question would be:

adding the following kernel parameters

i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
i915.i915_enable_fbc=1
i915.lvds_downclock=1
pcie_aspm=force
plus:

Adding to /etc/default/grub, Line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1"

(remember to sudo update-grub after editing)

I am new to Unix OS and i don't have knowledge on how to achieve above steps.

It would be really helpful, if some one provides me steps on above.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (using `sudo nano
     /etc/default/grub` or some other editor) and look for the line that looks something like:

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

(you may have different options in it)

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1"
```

i.e. add `pcie_aspm i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1` into the options

- Save the file and run:

  sudo update-grub